# how to extract a single digit in a number using regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

```
set phoneNumber 1234567890
```

this number single digit, i want divide this number into 123 456 7890 by using regexp. without using split function is it possible?

Comment: Why do you have to use regex?

Comment: »I have doubts about my hammer recently. I have a screw and I want to screw it in with the hammer, without using a screwdriver. Is it possible?«

Comment: What is this about single digit again? It looks like you want to group into 3-4-4 and not single digits.

Comment: @Johannes it is possible - just keep hitting... as long as YOU are not gonna have to take it out later, who cares.. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following snippet:

```
regexp {(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})} "8144658695" -> areacode first second

puts "($areacode) $first-$second"
```

Prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/2InqY)):

```
(814) 465-8695
```

This uses *capturing groups* in the pattern and `subMatchVar...` for Tcl `regexp`

#### References

- http://www.hume.com/html84/mann/regexp.html
- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### On the pattern

The regex pattern is:

```
(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})
\_____/\_____/\_____/
   1      2      3
```

It has 3 capturing groups `(…)`. The `\d` is a shorthand for the digit character class. The `{3}` in this context is "exactly 3 repetition of".

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Please down downvote for suggesting the `->` variable name. I got that from what I assume is an official authoritative documentation for idiomatic Tcl. Then again this is CW (for some reason?) so feel free to edit and improve any way you can.

Comment: Using the "->" dummy variable name is fairly common for regexp, since it 1) shows that you're not using that information, and 2) just looks nice (ie, kindof reads as "goes into").

Comment: +1 for the answer, where to get more info and explanation of the answer in that order. If I could I would give another +1 for the pretty formatting and concise, clear language.

Comment: Be aware; if you're working with international phone numbers the way you break things up into groups varies at the country level. And in fact below that level too (e.g., the UK has area codes for land-lines only, not mobile numbers, and the prefix numbers determine the structure of the following numbers; area codes are of variable length).

Comment: @ polygen thanks,i get example from http://cheminfo.informatics.indiana.edu/~rguha/class/2007/i211/week13/hw13.html, and i try that solution of that regular expression using singel regexp

Answer (score 0):

```
my($number) = "8144658695";

$number =~ m/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/;

my $num1 = $1;
my $num2 = $2;
my $num3 = $3;

print $num1 . "\n";
print $num2 . "\n"; 
print $num3 . "\n";
```

This is writen for Perl and works assuming the number is in the exact format you specified, hope this helps.

This site might help you with regex
http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm

Comment: oops lol, not doing well today, will go check that it works in TCL as well then

Comment: with Perl, you should check that the match actually succeeded before you start using $1, $2, etc